# How can I inject spring beans into jersey's resources class?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

First I define a jersey resource, it defines a class GetAllProgramDesc, then inject a java beans "IDataDevProgram" into it.

```
   @Path("/datadev")
   public class GetAllProgramDesc {


private IDataDevProgram dataProgram;

public IDataDevProgram getDataProgram() {
    return dataProgram;
}

public void setDataProgram(IDataDevProgram dataProgram) {
    this.dataProgram = dataProgram;
}


// The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media
// type "text/plain"
@GET @Path("/mbpprograms") 
@Produces("application/json")
public String getClichedMessage() {
    // Return some cliched textual content
    List<MbpProgram> list=dataProgram.showMbpProgramList(21294551);
    return JSONObject.toJSONString(list);
}
```

}

Then I wanna to inject a java beans into jersey resource class:

```
<bean id="dataDevProgram" class="com.taobao.gemstone.data.mbpapi.datadev.DataDevProgram">
    <property name="mDBops" ref="dataDevDBOps" />
    <property name="sqlManager" ref="sqlManger" />
    <property name="actionManager" ref="actionManger" />
    <property name="dataManager" ref="dataManageImpl" />
    <property name="constant" ref="constantproperty"/>
</bean>

<bean id="datadevrest"    class="com.taobao.gemstone.data.mbpapi.restresources.GetAllProgramDesc">
    <property name="dataProgram" ref="dataDevProgram" />
</bean>
```

However, when i send a query to this url, the whole process crashed as follows:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.taobao.gemstone.data.mbpapi.restresources.GetAllProgramDesc.getClichedMessage(GetAllProgramDesc.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

is there any method to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Spring in Jersey you can use one of the following:

Inject `@Context ServletContext context;` into your resource class,

then use code such as:

`WebApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
        IDataDevProgram dataProgram  = applicationContext.getBean(IDataDevProgram .class);`

Alternatively, you can also use jersey support for IoC container:

`@InjectParam IDataDevProgram dataProgram`

You will have to use `jersey-spring` contrib and apply `SpringServlet` in your `web.xml`, there are numerous short tutorials which explain how to do that